# Paypal checkout with redirection?

Tags: javascript, php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to implement paypal checkout. I found this bit of code which is near perfect for me but not quite :

```
onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
    // Get the payment details
    return actions.payment.get().then(function(data) {
        // Display the payment details and a confirmation button
        var shipping = data.payer.payer_info.shipping_address;
        document.querySelector('#recipient').innerText = shipping.recipient_name;
        document.querySelector('#line1').innerText     = shipping.line1;
        document.querySelector('#city').innerText      = shipping.city;
        document.querySelector('#state').innerText     = shipping.state;
        document.querySelector('#zip').innerText       = shipping.postal_code;
        document.querySelector('#country').innerText   = shipping.country_code;
        document.querySelector('#paypal-button-container').style.display = 'none';
        document.querySelector('#confirm').style.display = 'block';
        // Listen for click on confirm button
        document.querySelector('#confirmButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
            // Disable the button and show a loading message
            document.querySelector('#confirm').innerText = 'Loading...';
            document.querySelector('#confirm').disabled = true;
            // Execute the payment
            return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
                // Show a thank-you note
                document.querySelector('#thanksname').innerText = shipping.recipient_name;
                document.querySelector('#confirm').style.display = 'none';
                document.querySelector('#thanks').style.display = 'block';
            });
        });
    });
}
```

I would like to redirect the user on an other php page when payment is Authorized. Will I still be able to call functions actions.payment.get() and actions.payment.execute() ? If yes, how should I proceed to call them ? If not, why ?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your php url when you create the payment passing the urls to the create request payment with the **redirect_urls** property

```
{
  intent: "sale",
  ...
  redirect_urls :
  {
    return_url : "http://youreturnurl.com/finished",
    cancel_url : "http://youreturnurl.com/canceled"
  },
  ...
  transactions: [ {
     ...
  }]
  ...
}
```

and you just need to call **`actions.redirect()`** inside your then method after the `get()`.

```
onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
  return actions.payment.get().then(function(data) {
   //do extra actions
   ...
   return actions.redirect();
}}
```

You can do the same for the `onCancel()` or simply close the popup with `actions.close()`.